# Facebook share restrict the "only me" option

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

Using the FB Share dialog, is there a way to prevent the user from selecting "Only Me" in the custom privacy settings?

Thanks!
Uri

Comment: That’s the user’s choice, and you can not influence it. (And should you be thinking about rewarding the user for sharing or something like that, please go read Platform Policies, because that is not allowed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the privacy setting is completely up to the user and you should not think about limiting his options there. I can´t think of any use case where this would be necessary anyway, to be honest.